# Assigning Object.prototype causes issues with jQuery

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to assign a function to Object.prototype.equals similar to what's done in [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript). The function works perfectly, but whenever I have jQuery about, I get errors like:

> name.replace is not a function

referring to line 6490 in jquery-1.6.1.js.

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Comment: Even if I remove the function body, just returning true, I get the same issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827458/prototyping-object-in-javascript-breaks-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't monkey patch `Object.prototype`.

```
Object.prototype.replace = "lol";

for (var i in { "bar": 42 }) {
  alert(i);
}
// "bar"
// "replace" :(
```

Basically `for ... in` loops iterate over all properties in an object *including* ones defined on the prototype. This is why it's really bad practice to extend or change `Object.prototype`.

Some people also go as far as "Don't monkey patch `Array`, `String`, `Function`, ...".

You should **never** mess with the `Object.prototype`. The rest of the native prototypes are a style choice.

Define your function on `Object`.

```
Object.replace = function() { ... };

var o = Object.replace(p);
```

**ES5:**

With ecmascript 5 you can set properties as non-enumerable

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "replace", {
  value: function() { }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm just gonna create a standalone function.