# adding methods to Object prototype causes an error when twitter bootstrap modal is closed

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a very weird issue.

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 2.  I have a modal dialogue on a page, which I am opening like this:

`$('#rights-dialogue).modal();`

I am also adding a custom function to the `Object.prototype` object, like this:

`Object.prototype.foo = function (a) {};`

When the `x` button in the modal dialogue is clicked, the dialogue closes, but the black background remains and I get a strange jQuery error in the jQuery event handling code:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'origType' of undefined`

If I remove all arguments from my `foo()` function, I do not not get this error, and everything works fine.

Here is a jsfiddle that illustrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/nicholascloud/r6T8z/5/.

I have **no idea** what's going on here.

---

EDIT: A few other things I've noticed.

It doesn't seem to matter what the name of the method is on Object.prototype. Any method **with arguments** will cause this error.  If a method is added with no arguments, the error does not occur.

The error occurs when jQuery detaches the event listener `keyup.dismiss.modal` from the DOM.

I have confirmed this error with jQuery 1.7.1 and 1.7.2, but my suspicion is that its a Twitter Bootstrap problem and not jQuery per se.

Comment: I'm not getting any black background or exceptions after closing the modal in that JSFiddle.

Comment: I should have been more specific. You have to uncomment the second `Object.prototype...` line.  Also, the error will only show in the console.

Comment: And by console I mean, the Chrome/Firefox dev console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with jQuery and extending Object.prototype.

See this question: [Prototyping Object in Javascript breaks jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827458/prototyping-object-in-javascript-breaks-jquery)

Essentially, you should avoid extending Object.prototype, but see the answer for more details.

Comment: Thanks so much for the link -- I did not realize that this was a convention required by jQuery.