# Is there a jQuery way of iterating over an objects own properties only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration, for-in-loop, hasownproperty

I'm making a small jQuery-like library, and one thing striking me odd is the behavior of [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

In javascript we have a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    console.log(key + ': ' + obj[key]);
}
```

The problem with this, is that it will iterate over *inherited* properties as well, that is, properties coming from the object constructor's prototype.

One can know this using [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), for example. And jQuery *could* do that.

But, when you pass an object to `$.each`, it behaves *exactly* like a `for...in`, iterating over inherited properties as well. It also should be marginally slower, and requires a few more characters to type.

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpTkA/) to see it in action and [look here](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.each) for the source code of `$.each`.

So my question is, is there an *object* iteration method in jQuery that only includes own properties? If not, should a library behave like this?

**Edit:** Since jQuery does not do this, you can also answer if this is useful. I mean, I cannot see myself wanting to iterate over prototype properties, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Have a look here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827458/prototyping-object-in-javascript-breaks-jquery

Comment: The only way to find it is by using `hasOwnProperty`. http://jsfiddle.net/mpTkA/2/

Comment: There's also `Object.keys()` in newer browsers.

Comment: agreed, with @Vega, afraid this is the only way, no sugar from jQuery in this prospective

Comment: @dmi3y Ah, I see, that's sad. I wonder if a library is supposed to behave this way, since I'm having to decide that at the moment.

Comment: @Vega I even mentioned `hasOwnProperty` in the question.

Comment: @CamiloMartin Yes I know.. that is why It was not in answers :)

Comment: @Pointy, good to know) probably the [`getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) would be even better

Comment: @dmi3y Not if you need to support IE8.

Comment: yep, that's why it is not the answer) just bit more information for future

Comment: **Quick note:** Make sure that if you use the native `for`-`in`, you use a `var` for the `key`: `for (var key in obj)`. Otherwise you'll get an accidental global. (Unless you really want `key` to be global, in which case, you should likely find a better way of doing whatever it is you want to do.)

**Other quick note:** When using `hasOwnProperty`, it can be slightly safer to save a reference instead of calling it by dot-notation: `var has = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty; has.call({abc: 'xyz'}, 'abc');`.

Comment: @Cory oh yes, you're completely right. I missed that. And I can see your second point does make sense (albeit I'm not sure who would tinker with hasOwnProperty...).

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery behavior makes sense, as you can always choose to add the hasOwnProperty check in the loop - or not.

I can see that looping through inherited properties could be useful in some scenarios (cloning or sub-class or whatever you call it).

Comment: That "some scenarios" part is the one I couldn't figure out. Do you have any example? (And, if one has to add the `hasOwnProperty` check, one could as well use `for...in` and save some typing).

Comment: For example: defaultAjaxSettings={type:"GET",...}, then create a clone that has some specific settings but for the rest inherits from the default settings?

Comment: I see... but normally one uses something like `$.extend` to deal with defaults in option maps, right? Or in some framework it is more common to do it like this, with inheritance?

Comment: right... honestly I don't know. Obviously you'd want to use inheritance when you need to propagate changes to the default settings , but I don't have a better example.

Comment: Also, I think the interest of $.each is to provide an abstraction layer that works with various collections (objects, arrays), and this might be interesting in some scenarios like templating. But again I don't have a specific example...