# Converting plain javascript hash into proper object

Tags: javascript, oop

I need to add some more OO flavor to my pure JS objects. Basically, I have on the server side

```
class Superitem {
    List<Item> items;
    Whatever whatever;
}

class Item {
    List<Subitem> subitems;
    Whatever whatever;
}

class Subitem {
    List<Whatever> whatevers;
}
```

In the client, I get a superitem as a plain Javascript hash and would like to convert it to something better. I started like

```
 Superitem(plain) {
      this.items = plain && plain.items || [];
      this.whatever = new Whatever(plain.whatever);
 }
```

but it's too verbose (my real classes are more complicated) and I rather doubt if its worth the effort. I'm not trying to mimic Java in Javascript, just want to add a few useful methods. Is there a better way? Thing like `$.extend` seem to be useless here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.extend` is hardly useless. You could define the constructor[s] like so:

```
function Superitem(data) {
    $.extend(this, { items: [] }, data);
    this.whatever = new Whatever(this.whatever);
}
```

`$.extend` will inject into `this` first the defaults (`{ items: [] }`) and then the plain object provided to the function. It then converts `whatever` to a `Whatever`.

Comment: This sounds good, except that in the later steps I will possibly garble the original `data` (which may be needed somewhere). I guess making a deep copy of `data` at the very beginning solves it.

Comment: @maaartinus: Note that going through the structure, converting everything to an instance of one of your classes *is* a deep copy. In this case, since we didn’t touch `items` besides bringing it over, it isn’t a deep copy, but since we touched `whatever`, changing it would not affect the original `data`.

Comment: Yes, but this assumes I don't forget anything. As the next step I have to do something like `var self = this; $.each(self.items, function(i,v) {self.items[i] = new Item(v);}`, right? And check for `hasOwnProperty`, right?

Comment: @maaartinus: Indeed, it assumes you don’t forget anything. Doing a deep copy first would be safer. Case in point: you’d need to use `map` rather than `$.each`. If you put a `if(!(this isinstance Item)) return new Item(data);` at the top of the definition of `Item`, you could then rewrite that line as `this.items = this.items.map(Item);`. I don’t see where `hasOwnProperty` comes in if you’re providing defaults.

Comment: I mentioned `hasOwnProperty` because of `$.each` [iterating over everything](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688337/is-there-a-jquery-way-of-iterating-over-an-objects-own-properties-only) and I don't want to add any garbage.

Comment: @maaartinus: I’m guessing that only becomes a problem if you’re using it to iterate over something other than an array or you’ve touched `Array.prototype`. Either way, using `map` does not possess the same caveats, although it’s unavailable in older browsers (though can be shimmed; see es5-shim).

Answer (score 0):

Object *hashes* as you say *are* already regular, normal objects.

jQuery's `extend` method works if you are trying to merge multiple properties/methods, but it isn't needed.

```
// Create an object through JSON, just to show its a regular
// object.
var obj = JSON.parse('{"prop" : true}');
obj.method = function() {alert(this.prop)};

obj.method();
```

Comment: But I don't want to add the method directly to all instances. This makes debugging much worse as the methods obfuscate the content.

Comment: Then you'll have to update your question and let us know what you *are* trying to add methods to.

Comment: To the prototype. That's why I need to create the object via the constructor... at least I think so. Sorry for being imprecise.