# jQuery conflict with native prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, conflict

I have a problem using jQuery with native JavaScript (**NOT** prototype.js). When using the following code, jQuery 1.9.1 with an error message:

```
Object.prototype.myVeryGreatFunction = function() {
    // ...
}

[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'U[a].exec(s)')
ft (jquery.min.js, line 4)
wt (jquery.min.js, line 4)
st (jquery.min.js, line 4)
find (jquery.min.js, line 4)
init (jquery.min.js, line 3)
b (jquery.min.js, line 3)
(anonymous function) (read.control.js, line 59)
c (jquery.min.js, line 3)
fireWith (jquery.min.js, line 3)
ready (jquery.min.js, line 3)
H (jquery.min.js, line 3)
```

When I remove the prototype definition, everything works great. Unfortunately I can't easily update jQuery because this is in a plugin for a CMS, so it has to work with old versions for compatibility reasons.

Is there any known issue with that or a fix for that?

Googling actually shows me solutions like using `jQuery.noConflict()` and private function wrapping. But as mentioned above I'm not using prototype.js, but **native** JS object prototyping.

Comment: can you provide us a fiddle

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prototyping Object in Javascript breaks jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827458/prototyping-object-in-javascript-breaks-jquery)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can avoid these problems by making your extensions to the native prototypes as non-enumerable:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'myVeryGreatFunction',{
  value : function() {},
  enumerable : false
});
```

`Object.defineProperty` documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

As Jan Dvorak mentioned, this solution does not work for old browsers (IE8-).

Comment: Legend! Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 3):

There is **no safe way** in older browsers to extend `Object.prototype` without breaking jQuery.  The jQuery authors specifically say (somewhere...) that jQuery will break if you just add new enumerable properties to `Object.prototype`.

The only **safe** way requires ECMAScript 5, and its `Object.defineProperty` function, which allows *non-enumerable* properties to be added to objects.

The jQuery `noconflict()` function doesn't help - it's a solution to an entirely different problem.