# Uncaught TypeError: X[g].exec is not a function fb tokenize

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeerror, toastr

Since today I am getting an error as follows:

`Uncaught TypeError: X[g].exec is not a function fb tokenize`

This is the stack trace:

`Uncaught TypeError: X[g].exec is not a function
 fb.tokenize @ jquery.min.js:2
 fb.compile @ jquery.min.js:2
 fb.select @ jquery.min.js:2
 fb @ jquery.min.js:2
 m.event.handlers @ jquery.min.js:3
 m.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
 r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3`

The project is an Angularjs app built in an .NET MVC Area.
Dependencies are:

- http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css and corresponding js
- https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js
- /Resources/Libs/AngularJS/Libs/angular-file-upload-shim.min.js
- /Resources/Libs/AngularJS/Libs/bootstrap.min.js/Resources/Libs/AngularJS/Libs/wysihtml5-0.3.0.min.js
- /Resources/Libs/AngularJS/Libs/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.js
- http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.js"

## Edit

Seems to be a problem with Bootstrap.js file, where an alert is supposed to be dismissed but not found. JQuery Sizzle can't find `"[alert-dismiss]"`.
The fb is Sizzle in minified version of JQuery.

Comment: I recommend finding out more information about what exactly is broken here. One way do approach this would be to not use minified versions of the code involved in your development/testing setup, and include debug symbols wherever appropriate.

Comment: i think it will work for you..
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729895/jquery-conflict-with-native-prototype)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the culprit.

Seems there was a disturbance in the force with the combination of bootstrap.js and the angular bootstrap ui library. After removing the unnecessary bootstrap.js all was well.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same `X[g].exec is not a function` error and in my case it was because i defined a `Object.prototype.count` function.

Comment: I had a similar experience and it drives home the point - do not extend the Object prototype. It will mess up jQuery (I'm willing to bet Gecko IT's solution was because bootstrap extends the Object).

Answer (score 1):

To solve that, add the following to your code:

```
Function.prototype.exec = Object.prototype.exec = function() {return null};
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was trying to get the index of a non-indexed array to iterate it. The code was:

```js
Object.prototype.getByIndex = function(index) {
    return this[Object.keys(this)[index]];
  };
```

`this`  keyword represented the data I was trying to get the index of. So using it would be:

```js
// ...
const element = groupedData.getByIndex(index);
// ...
```

---

To fix this, I modified it to be a regular function, then pass the data as a parameter. The new function would look like this:

```js
function getByIndex(grupData, index) {
    return grupData[Object.keys(grupData)[index]];
  };
```

And passing the data:

```js
const element = getByIndex(groupedData, index);
```