# jQuery not work in some sites

Tags: jquery

For example, open http://camel.apache.org/ ,
then open the console in Chrome or Firefox, 
execute the code bellow for jQuery injection:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
```

Will get error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

at jQuery.js line 3536:

```
return readyList.promise( obj ); // 'promise' is an undefined function.
```

Comment: unforgettably Google don't let some countries to have access to some of its websites, for example if you are in Iran you can't have access to code.google.com or ajax.googleapis.com

Comment: @Kermani Clearly they were able to get jQuery to download - the error is happening inside the jQuery file while it's executing.

Comment: @Kermani I can access ajax.googleapis.com

Comment: Are there other scripts on the page? I would expect this would only happen if some other script is somehow modifying global variables or types in a way that conflicts with jQuery. Javascript can do some funky things if people are not careful, like overwriting prototypes for built-in types or other craziness. I'd suggest taking out the other scripts one-by-one, and seeing if you can track down one which might be causing the problem.

Comment: @JoeEnos I saw that page is using prototype.js, but I think jQuery can work well with other libraries as jQuery have a  jQuery.noConfilct() method

Comment: @JoeEnos Hi Joe, I find the reason, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In that same page if you add:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
```

It will work.

When you use `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js` without `https:` or `http:` it automatically tries to get one of them depending on some factors. In this case it tries to get `http:` but the site only accepts references to `https:` so it will fail.

Here is a quote from another post:

> Using a protocol-independent absolute
>   path:
>
> ```
> <img src="//domain.com/img/logo.png"/>
> ```
>
> If the browser is viewing an page in
>   SSL through HTTPS, then it'll request
>   that asset with the https protocol,
>   otherwise it'll request it with HTTP.
>
> This prevents that awful "This Page
>   Contains Both Secure and Non-Secure
>   Items" error message in IE, keeping
>   all your asset requests within the
>   same protocol.
>
> Caveat: When used on a `<link>` or
>   @import for a stylesheet, IE7 and IE8
>   [download the file twice](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/02/10/5a-missing-schema-double-download/). All other
>   uses, however, are just fine.

Comment: Hi, I tried your script(in Chrome), but got the same error.

Comment: Works on mine, sorry. I didn't expect to get a downvote for trying to help other people.

Comment: If this was the problem, then jQuery wouldn't have downloaded successfully in the first place. CDNs tend to have the files located at both HTTP and HTTPS, specifically so that you can use the `//ajax.googleapis.com/` syntax and get the secure or non-secure version, to match your current page.

Comment: What's your browser? It not works for me, but thanks for your help.

Comment: @JoeEnos sometimes it fails my friend, I have experienced that in some scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Answer my questions:

Some sites define the prototype of `Object`, like:

```
  if (!Object.prototype.extend) {
    Object.prototype.extend = function(){}
  }
```

It will break jQuery.

Here is similar question [Prototyping Object in Javascript breaks jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827458/prototyping-object-in-javascript-breaks-jquery)

And [an advice from John Resig](http://markmail.org/message/tv7vxcir6w3p2h5e) : `we're looking into for the future, but
please don't do it, regardless of the state of jQuery.`

It posted on 6 years ago, but seems it will not be solved.

Here is a solution from [the bug ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2721#comment:6) :

```
    for (var i in O) {
        if (!O.hasOwnProperty(i)) { continue; }// Add this to all `for...in` loops
        // other code stays unchanged
    }
```

but this way, you have to create a customized jQuery(so you can not import jQuery from public CDN).