# Angular what is the best way to access total objects within ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Accessing thhe the length of items within a ng-repeat seems simple. `{{array.length}}`

But when you have to iterate trough objects and you have to know the total
objects then you don't have a Angular thing for it.

What I did now is count the total properties and store it in a variable.

```
$scope.totalPersons =  Object.keys($scope.data).length;
```

But when items are added to the object the `totalPersons` is not updated so 
I changed this so the value will be updated.

```
$scope.$watch( $scope.data, function (newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.totalPersons = Object.keys($scope.data).length;
});
```

But is there a better way to access the total objects in your template?

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
        {{key}} - {{value}}  {{totalPersons}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What's the type of $scope.data?

Answer (score 2):

by creating a custom filter that return the `Object.keys` you can get the length of the object keys

```js
angular.module('customfilter', []).filter('keys', function() {
  return function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='customfilter' ng-init="data={a:1,b:2}">
<p>the array: {{ data | keys}}</p>
  <p>the array length: {{ (data | keys).length}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define a filter for it and you can also avoid manual `$watch` for it by using a $scope function:

```
$scope.totalPersons = function() {
    return Object.keys($scope.data).length;
};
```

Now, simply call this method in your HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">{{key}} - {{value}} -{{totalPersons()}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

In this way, Angular will self-update the count. Cheers :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can extend the prototype of object but that is a general solution which reflects on all objects.

```
Object.prototype.size = function(){
  return Object.keys(this).length
};
```

And then:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">{{key}} - {{value}} -{{data.size()}}
```

or

```
<ul ng-init="totalPersons=data.size()">
   <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">{{key}} - {{value}} -{{totalPersons}}
```

Comment: Well, just FYI, extending `Object.prototype` is not recommended and also has some side effects. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827458/prototyping-object-in-javascript-breaks-jquery

Comment: Also improper to use `ng-init` for such purposes.