# How to get a type of scope variable in Angular expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, types

Let's define simple boolean on the scope:

```
var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', []);

mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.b = false;
});
```

How can I get type of a variable in the expression? `typeOf` and `Object.prototype.Tostring.call` don't work.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
        <div>
          {{ b }}
          {{ typeOf(b) }}
          {{ Object.prototype.toString.call(b) }}
        </div>
</div>
```

Here's JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g8Ld80x3/2/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

i think the best way is to create a custom filter and use it as you wish within you expression, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845550/angular-what-is-the-best-way-to-access-total-objects-within-ng-repeat-directive/35846185#35846185) link that use for get the Object.keys of an object

for your case you can use

```
angular.module('customfilter', []).filter('typeof', function() {
  return function(obj) {
    return typeof obj
  };
});
```

Comment: Great idea! Simple and robust. I like it.

Comment: Why hasn't this been built into Angular?  Maybe it already has in Angular 2.  Doesn't look like it though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511055/how-to-check-type-of-variable-in-ngif-in-angular2.

Answer (score 7):

Just to show Zamboney's answer applied to my sample code:

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('customfilter', []).filter('getType', function() {
  return function(obj) {
    return typeof obj
  };
});

var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', ['customfilter']);

mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.b = false;
});
```

**View:**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
  <div>
    {{ b }}
    {{ b | getType }}
    <div ng-if="(b | getType) == 'number'">
      It's a number
    </div>
    <div ng-if="(b | getType) == 'boolean'">
      It's a boolean
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g8Ld80x3/5/

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it and for the good reason: [Angular expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) parser disallows such sort of things in the templates.

If you really want to be able to do so, I recommend to explicitly set helper methods on the `$rootScope` so it will be available in all your templates:

```
mymodal.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.typeOf = function(value) {
        return typeof value;
    };
});
```

You can even reference Angular own utility methods:

```
 mymodal.run(function($rootScope) {
    ['isArray', 'isDate', 'isDefined', 'isFunction', 'isNumber', 'isObject', 'isString', 'isUndefined'].forEach(function(name) {
        $rootScope[name] = angular[name];
    });
});
```

and use `{{ isArray(arr) }}` in templates.

Comment: This is great answer and thank you very much. But Zamboney's idea to create filter is to me better. Anyway - thanks again.

Comment: Actually, filter in this case is very bad idea, due to at least 2 reasons, but whatever  is better for you.

Comment: What are disadvantages?

Comment: Filters are not very performant. Then how are you going to use it in ngIf for example? You can but this is clumsy.

Comment: When it comes to the usage I thought about this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35862140/angularjs-change-input-type-dynamically/35862384 .

What's the second reason?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in the controller(I don't think is possible directly in the expression as you want to do):

```js
var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', []);

mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.b = false;
    $scope.getBType = function(test){
        return( typeof test);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='mymodal' ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
        <div>
          {{ getBType(b) }}
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to do it in a controller. I want to execute typeof in expression. Also in `ng-if` or `ng-show`/`ng-hide` directives.

Comment: First, you have to do it in the controller then you return it to the expression.

Comment: Shouldn't this rather return string than calling alert?

Comment: You can use return method instead of alert then. Important thing is that it's working. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
        <div>
          {{ b }}<br>
          {{ typeOf(b) }}<br>
        </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', []);

mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.b = false;
    $scope.typeOf = function (v){ return (typeof v)};
});
```

RESULT

```
false
boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to access the type `typeof` of the specific value and in the current code you are doing this in the `view` which is quite late for such operation.

Instead you can make a function in the controller's scope and just return it from there:

```js
var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', []);

mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.b = false;
    $scope.getTypeof = function(it){ return typeof(it); };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='mymodal' ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
        <div>
          {{ b }} : {{ getTypeof(b) }}
          
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.b = new String('name');
```

// according to the above statement, the object will be the result of the typeof operator. It does not check the type of the typeof operator: http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#types.typeof