# Type casting within a template in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on an Angular project (Angular 4.0.0) and I'm having trouble binding a property of an abstract class to ngModel because I first need to cast it as the concrete class it actually is in order to access the property.

i.e. I have an AbstractEvent class this has a  a concrete implementation Event which has a boolean property 'acknowledged' which I need a two way binding via ngModel to set with a checkbox.

I currently have this element in my DOM:

```
<input type="checkbox" *ngIf="event.end" [(ngModel)]="(event as Event).acknowledged" 
                                          [disabled]="(event as Event).acknowledged">
```

Unfortunately this is throwing the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 8 in [(event as Event).acknowledged]

Googling around seemed to suggest this might be because using 'as' is not supported when using it inside a template? Although I'm not certain about this.

I also can't work out how to just write a function for it in my typescript file driving the template because this would break the two way binding on ngModel that I require.

If anyone has any way to get around this or perform type casting in angular templates correctly I would be very appreciative!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As mentioned, using a barebone method call will have performance impact.

A better approach is to use a pipe, and you have best of both worlds. Just define a Cast pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'cast',
  pure: true
})
export class CastPipe implements PipeTransform {  
  transform(value: any, args?: any): Event {
    return value;
  }
}
```

and then in your template, use `event | cast` when you need the cast.

That way, change detection stays efficient, and typing is safe (given the requested type change is sound of course).

Unfortunately, I don't see a way to have this generic because of the `name` attribute, so you'd have to define a new pipe for each type.

Comment: You can make it general for classes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66154034/1990451

Comment: This solution works.  I wanted to cast an AbstractControl to a FormGroup from within the template and access a control value.  Creating an asformgroup Pipe worked for me.

Answer (score 90):

If you don't care about type control.

In Angular **8 and higher versions**

```
[(ngModel)]="$any(event).acknowledged"
```

From Offical Document: https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#disabling-type-checking-using-any

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '{{$any(person).addresss.street}}'
})
class MyComponent {
  person?: Person;
}
```

Comment: This is like hiding the trash under the carpet. It works, but we should rarely use it.

Comment: Not really imo. Sometimes you know things that the compiler doesn't. I don't know of any better way to handle those situations.

Comment: What about a simple getter function in the Component class? 
The type should be known there or it can be cast as needed. 
// template
`<input ... [(ngModel)]="getEvent()" />`

Comment: It's good to use for debugging

Comment: **In my case I did not have an event but an object with a union type property**. The compiler did not understand that my ngSwitch statement made sure only one type is possible. I needed to delete the '.acknowledged' part to make it work: ```[(ngModel)]="$any(obj.unionTypeProperty)"```

Answer (score 49):

That's not possible because `Event` can't be referenced from within the template.

(`as` is also not supported in template binding expressions)

<strike>You need to make it available first:</strike>

```
class MyComponent {
  EventType = Event;
```

then this should work

```
[(ngModel)]="(event as EventType).acknowledged"
```

**update**

```
class MyComponent {
  asEvent(val) : Event { return val; }
```

then use it as

```
[(ngModel)]="asEvent(event).acknowledged"
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply but I still seem to be getting the same error: "Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 8 in [(event as EventType).acknowledged]"

Comment: I updated my answer. It might have a notable effect on performance, because functions bound in templates are called quite often. I'd try to avoid using that if not necessary. Do you get errors without casting?

Comment: Thanks a lot that got it working. And yeah Im not too worried about performance. Currently working on a sort of prototype project written by a colleague of mine. In the future I will probably try to avoid this sort of design that requires casting. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: You're welcome :) The method is very simple and doesn't do anything (casting will be removed completely when TS is transpiled to JS), but change detection is most efficient when properties are directly checked without any getters or methods involved. Just something one should be aware when working with Angular.

Comment: your answer is great, but the act of not implementing such a feature, and talk big about inheritance and OOP, is so cheap of those people

Comment: See my answer below for a solution with pipe, avoiding the negative performance impact.

Comment: Bearing in mind that change detection will cause the casting function to be called many times, is there any other way we can achieve the same effect without using a function directly in the template? I've always been told to avoid this wherever possible.

Comment: @user9754798 doing such stuff in the template is usually a bad idea anyway. Ensure the component provides the values in the correct type. If the event and the property differ in type or need different treatment for some other reason, split them like `[ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="handleValueChange($event)"`

Comment: What does this 'acknowledged' mean in a template?

Comment: @AlexanderPoshtaruk this has to be something custom. You can dispatch custom DOM events. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Answer (score 35):

This pipe can be used to take the type from various inputs. It works pretty well with classes, named types / interfaces and primitives.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'as',
  pure: true,
})
export class AsPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform<T>(value: any, _type: (new (...args: any[]) => T) | T): T {
    return value as T;
  }

}
```

`_type` argument is unused, but is serving the main goal: the type gets inferred from the constructor / variable.

Could be used as:

```
class ClassEvent {
  prop: string;
}

interface InterfaceEvent {
  prop: string;
}

export class MyComponent {

  MyClass = ClassEvent; // class constructor

  MyInterface: InterfaceEvent; // typed property

  propString: any; // primitive, string

  propNumber: any; // primitive, number

}
```

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
  Type from class constructor: {{ (row | as : MyClass).prop }}
  Type from interface: {{ (row | as : MyInterface).prop }}
  Type from primitive, string: {{ (propString | as : '').substr(1) }}
  Type from primitive, number: {{ (propNumber | as : 123).toFixed(2) }}
</td>
```

Requires strict templates and Ivy.

Comment: Doesn't seems to be working in my case it says `Identifier 'a' is not defined. 'T' does not contain such a member`

Comment: Works in Angular 12 with "strictTemplates" enabled.

Comment: Check my fully generics [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69466380/1283715)

Comment: @KhaledLela your solution infers the type from the function that expects the type. It does not work for Material tables when there is nowhere to infer the type from

Comment: @smnbbrv You are completely correct, That why i extended my answer for another question [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69467612/1283715) to pass type explicitly as an argument, *Updated my answer and refer to your answer as mostly inspired from your answer explicit type but i forget to refer at that time, Thanks!*

Comment: Nice idea, but I personally don't prefer to abuse performance for type casting!

Comment: @MurhafSousli the performance impact of the solution should be as big as none. The pipe is pure, which means it runs only once until the value changes. The function call, when the pipe is called is just passing the value through, which would be most likely cut off by v8. One should really measure this. And, the type definitions are totally outweighting one function call unless you are writing a veeeery specific and sensitive application

Comment: Does this work with any type of class? What if I have a structured data model with derived classes and I have an array of this different objects declared with the type of the base class? How I do the casting then?  Plus, this: '_type: (new (...args: any[]) => T) | T' looks so ugly

Comment: Nice! This link below helped me understand the use of new () => T in the pipe definition, as it helps "refer to class types by their constructor functions". So in this way the class type can be passed there. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics

Answer (score 9):

- **Using my *TypeSafe* generics [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69466380/1283715):**
- **And inspired from [smnbbrv answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66154034/1283715) pass type
  explicitly as an optional argument when there is nowhere to infer the
  type from.**

  ```
   import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

   /**
    * Cast super type into type using generics
    * Return Type obtained by optional @param type OR assignment type.
    */

   @Pipe({ name: 'cast' })
   export class CastPipe implements PipeTransform {
       /**
        * Cast (S: SuperType) into (T: Type) using @Generics.
        * @param value (S: SuperType) obtained from input type.
        * @optional @param type (T CastingType)
        * type?: { new (): T }
        * type?: new () => T
        */
       transform<S, T extends S>(value: S, type?: new () => T): T {
           return <T>value;
       }
   }
  ```

  **Usage:**

  *template.html*

  ```
   <input
       type="checkbox"
       *ngIf="event.end"
       [(ngModel)]="(event | cast: Event).acknowledged"
       [disabled]="(event | cast: Event).acknowledged"
   />
  ```

  *component.ts*

  ```
   export abstract class AbstractEvent {
       end: boolean;
   }
   export class Event extends AbstractEvent {
       acknowledged: boolean;
   }


   export class MyComponent{
       event: AbstractEvent;
       Event = Event;
   }
  ```

Comment: I tried to use it as ```[parentForm]="(inspectionFormArray.get([i]) | castToType: FormGroup)```, but I received the error ```Argument of type 'typeof FormGroup' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => FormGroup'.```. Any idea?

Comment: @boludokid Take care about type `T = parentForm` must be extends `S = inspectionFormArray.get(i)`
try one of these two options, 
1. `castToType: AbstractControl.` 2. use `$any(inspectionFormArray.get([i]))`

Comment: Do you know how to cast to a primitive data type, like ```number``` or ```string```?

Answer (score 6):

You can also create a function that returns a [Type Predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

app.component.html

```html
<some-component *ngIf="isFoo(foo)" [foo]="foo"></some-component>
```

app.component.ts

```
isFoo(value: Foo | Bar): value is Foo {
    return value === 'Foo';
}
```

This will cast the template variable `foo` to type `Foo` and will silence any strictTemplate errors regarding union types.

Comment: This can actually be sufficient in some cases and it avoids the hassle of adding a pipe. Well played !

Answer (score 5):

To expand on the answer by @smnbbrv, you can use a similar syntax with interfaces as follows:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'as', pure: true })
export class AsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<T>(input: unknown, baseItem: T | undefined): T {
    return (input as unknown) as T;
  }
}
```

This requires us to provide a "baseItem" of the correct type. However, we do not need to actually create the item, we only need to declare it (since the item can be undefined). That means we can create a variable of the suggested type in our class as follows:

```
export interface Person{
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

export class MyComponent {
  Person: Person;
}
```

Take note, we're not assigning any value to the `baseItem`, we're simply specifying its type. If you have `strictPropertyInitialization` enabled, you will need to add a non-null assertion to your `baseItem`

```
export class MyComponent {
  Person!: Person;
}
```

This can then be used in your template as follows:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
  {{ (row | as : Person).name }}
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer! I'm the author of [ng-as](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-as) Angular library with pipe and directive for type casting template variables.

Casting with directirve eg.:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// your interface, but also work with any typescript type (class, type, etc.)
interface Person {
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="personTemplate; context: {$implicit: person}"></ng-container>
  <ng-template #personTemplate [ngAs]="Person" let-person>
    <span>Hello {{ person.name }}!</span>
  </ng-template>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  // NOTE: If you have "strictPropertyInitialization" enabled, 
  // you will need to add a non-null assertion (!)
  public Person!: Person; // publish your interface into html template
  person: Person = { name: 'Simone' }; // the data
}
```

Casting with pipe eg.:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// your interface, but also work with any typescript type (class, type, etc.)
interface Person {
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="personTemplate; context: {$implicit: person}"></ng-container>
  <ng-template #personTemplate let-person>
    <span>Hello {{ (person | as: Person).name }}!</span>
  </ng-template>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  // NOTE: If you have "strictPropertyInitialization" enabled, 
  // you will need to add a non-null assertion (!)
  public Person!: Person; // publish your interface into html template
  person: Person = { name: 'Simone' }; // the data
}
```

source of pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: 'as', pure: true })
export class NgAsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  transform<T>(input: unknown, baseItem: T | undefined): T {
    return input as unknown as T;
  }
}
```

source of directive:

```
import { Directive, Input } from "@angular/core";

interface NgAsContext<T> {
  ngLet: T;
  $implicit: T;
}

@Directive({ selector: '[ngAs]' })
export class NgAsDirective<T> {
  @Input() ngAs!: T;

  static ngTemplateContextGuard<T>(dir: NgAsDirective<T>, ctx: any): ctx is NgAsContext<Exclude<T, false | 0 | '' | null | undefined>> {
      return true;
  }
}
```

More info on: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-as

Answer (score 0):

This is still not supported by Angular. You can create a custom pipe or a function to typecast.

Or **you can cast it to 'any' using the following syntax: $any()** .

Example:

```
{{$any(person).address.street}}
```

Reference doc: https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck