# Convert string to Typescript enum in Angular 6 template statement

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-template

I have a simple Angular 6 app with an Angular Material [select component](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) which I'd like to two-way bind to a enum variable. To do this I'll need to convert between string value which is used to identify the options and enum value which is the actual Typescript type. To convert string to enum I have always done this (assuming Value1 is a member of MyEnum):

```
let s: string = "Value1";
let myEnumVariable: MyEnum = MyEnum[s];
```

but this doesn't seem to work in Angular template statements, e.g. for the following:

**app.component.html:**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Select a value" [value]="MyEnum[myVariable]" (valueChange)="myVariable = MyEnum[$event]">
    <mat-option value="Value1">Value 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="Value2">Value 2</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  public myVariable: MyEnum = MyEnum.Value1;
  public MyEnum = MyEnum;
}

enum MyEnum {
  Value1,
  Value2
}
```

Everything is fine when developing with Angular development server. But once I run `ng build --prod`, this error appears:

> ERROR in src\app\app.component.html(2,73): : Type 'string' is not
>   assignable to type 'MyEnum'.

Why would this appear in building but not development? Any idea how to fix this, without using an explicit method call in the template statement?

Thanks a lot!

P.S I'm using Typescript 2.7.2

Comment: `(change)="myVariable = $any(MyEnum[$event]);"`

Comment: @yurzui This fixes it! But Angular in VS code gives a static checking error - [Angular] Unknown method '$any'. Any way to remove that? And if you wish you may post this as an answer and I can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: It looks like Angular language service doesn't support $any yet but AOT does https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#disabling-type-checking-using-any

Comment: This is why it doesn't work in aot. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bpgmal?file=src/app/app.component.ts AOT handles `$event` as `any`.

Comment: Another option you can try is `(change)="myVariable = MyEnum['' + $event];"`

Comment: This makes a lot of sense now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
let s = 'Value1' as 'Value1';
let myEnumVariable: MyEnum = MyEnum[s];
```

The error you had is because Typescript considered that `s` had type `string` and not `Value1`. But the enum has definite keys `Value1` and `Value2`, not any string. Hence the error.

> Why would this appear in building but not development?

Probably while development you have a file watcher that compiles your TS to JS even if there are some errors. I have the same watcher in my VSCode. However the errors are still there and the building process will therefore throw an error.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not the problem. If I didn't make it clear in the question, the problem is with template statement in Angular event binding where I'm trying to set the value of an enum variable

Comment: Hey @scharnyw Did it help? I've updated it multiple times.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! Unfortunately Angular template statement doesn't accept Typescript "as" operator. Btw the conversion from string to enum works fine when debugging under ng serve (I've checked that the binding works), it even works with ng build (I've hosted the files generated and checked in browser), but for some reason it doesn't work with ng build --prod. Seems to me this must be some rather strange features with Angular production build/optimizations.

Comment: The fact that ng build --prod does not work is good because it should not pass type errors. Regarding type casting in templates maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45964576/type-casting-within-a-template-in-angular-2

Comment: Ok. It does seem that there is no choice but to have a method in TS for this purpose. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your template doesn't recognise it as an `enum` so you need to just assign it as a string and read it as a `enum` in `typescript` - I'm not sure that this the correct way but you can give a try

Every `enum` will match the values with key pars and consider passing the key and get desired output in your `enum` key seems to be a `number` and you are trying to fetch it as a `string` so chage it like this

```
enum MyEnum {
  Value1 = "Value1",
  Value2 = "Value2"
}
```

Now when your read it as `MyEnum.Value1.toString()` it will return you the specific value as "Value1"

Now read it like this `public myVariable: string = MyEnum.Value1.toString()` passing to the template should ne `string` property if you want to read it in `ts` you can pass the desired `string` to get the value from `enum`

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Select a value" [value]="myVariable" (valueChange)="myVariable = $event">
    <mat-option value="Value1">Value 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="Value2">Value 2</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I hope this will help you - try to build your project in `ng build --prod` and check whether it works - Happy coding!!

Comment: This most certainly will work. But does that mean that it's impossible to bind an enum variable directly in Angular?

Comment: No its not like that you can bind in `template` it will work for dev build - but i had a issue like you in prod build so i found a way to get it :) hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks! yurzui found and explained a solution in the question comments. It's to do with the way Angular AOT treats template statements.