# Angular 9 with fullTemplateTypeCheck and strictTemplates enabled: Property does not exist on type

Tags: angular, angular9

i have a component like

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

interface ItemBaseType {
   foo: boolean;
}

interface ItemType extends ItemBaseType {
   bar: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'ac-foo',
  template: `<div *ngIf="item.bar">Hello</div>`,
})
export class FooComponent {
   public item: ItemType;
}
```

I have enabled [fullTemplateTypeCheck and strictTemplates](https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options#fulltemplatetypecheck)  on Angular 9 app and it raise exception when run `ng serve`:

> Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'ItemBaseType'.

But `bar` exist on `ItemType`.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a plunker or something please?

Comment: `*ngIf="item?.bar"`

Comment: Check my template TypeSafe casting using pipe [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69493142/1283715)

Answer (score 1):

You can use item?.bar in this case. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Check my template TypeSafe casting [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69467612/1283715) using pipe:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Cast super type into type using generics
 * Return Type obtained by optional @param type OR assignment type.
 */

@Pipe({ name: 'cast' })
export class CastPipe implements PipeTransform {
    /**
     * Cast (S: SuperType) into (T: Type) using @Generics.
     * @param value (S: SuperType) obtained from input type.
     * @optional @param type (T CastingType)
     * @returns (T: Type) obtained by optional @param type OR assignment type.
     */
    transform<S, T extends S>(value: S, type?: { new (): T }): T {
        return <T>value;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

interface ItemBaseType {
   foo: boolean;
}

interface ItemType extends ItemBaseType {
   bar: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'ac-foo',
  template: `<div *ngIf="item.bar | cast: ItemType">Hello</div>`,
})
export class FooComponent {
   // public item: ItemType; // Your case should be ItemBaseType
   // Expected your case reference to supertype that doesn’t directly contains bar property item refer to super type.
   public item: ItemBaseType; 
   ItemType = ItemType;  // ItemType alias for template reference.
}
```