# error TS2739: Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl': registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am a newbie in Angular and following an online course using *Angular 10* but stuck at one point. I am trying to implement the **Reactive forms**.
For that, I have added a new component *text-input*. The code for the `text-input.component.ts` is as follows:

```
import { Component, Input, Self } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-input',
  templateUrl: './text-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-input.component.css']
})
// We need to implement a control value accessor
export class TextInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() type = 'text';

  constructor(@Self() public ngControl: NgControl) {
    this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
  }
  writeValue(obj: any): void {
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
  }
}
```

Here is the code for the `text-input.component.html`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input [class.is-invalid]="ngControl.touched && ngControl.invalid" type="{{type}}" 
    class="form-control"
    [formControl]="ngControl.control" placeholder="{{label}}">

    <div *ngIf='ngControl.control.errors?.required' class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a {{label}}</div>
    <div *ngIf='ngControl.control.errors?.minlength' 
    class="invalid-feedback">{{label}} must be at least {{ngControl.control.errors.minlength['requiredLength']}}</div>

    <div *ngIf='ngControl.control.errors?.maxlength' class="invalid-feedback">{{label}} must be at most {{ngControl.control.errors.maxlength['requiredLength']}}</div>

    <div *ngIf='ngControl.control.errors?.isMatching' class="invalid-feedback">
        Password do not match</div>
</div>
```

But as soon as I add the code `[formControl]` I start getting the error:

```
 Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl': registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange, _applyFormState

4     [formControl]="ngControl.control" placeholder="{{label}}">
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/_forms/text-input/text-input.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './text-input.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component TextInputComponent.
```

The course Instructor is trying to generate the input controls inside a register component using this component, the code looks like this in `register.component.html`

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="register()" autocomplete="off">
    <h2 class="text-center text-primary">Sign up</h2>
    <hr>
    <app-text-input [formControl]='registerForm.controls["username"]' [label]='"Username"'></app-text-input>



    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-dark mr-2" type="submit">Register</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success mr-2" (click)="cancel()" type="button">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And there is a glimpse of `register.component.ts`

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, ValidatorFn, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { AccountService } from '../_services/account.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() cancelRegister = new EventEmitter();
  model: any = {};
  registerForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private accountService: AccountService, private toastr: ToastrService, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.intitializeForm();
  }
  intitializeForm() {
    this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required]
      
    })
  } 
  register = () => {
    console.log(this.registerForm.value);
   
  }  
}
```

Please do let me know what else you need, being new to Angular I am not able to find the route cause, but if you help me out then I shall move further with my course and would really thankful.

Comment: Your TextInputComponent in not implemented properly, there is no data binding. how it will take a input. Did you test it as a standalone component

Comment: Enabling strictTemplates mode is helpful to prevent passing wrong types errors,
Check my cast/TypeSafe [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69466380/1283715)

Comment: This works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67834802/template-error-type-abstractcontrol-is-not-assignable-to-type-formcontrol/72517767#72517767

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Template error Type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to type 'FormControl'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67834802/template-error-type-abstractcontrol-is-not-assignable-to-type-formcontrol)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you using Angular 11 in strict mode here?  If so change your tsconfig.json file and set:

`"strictTemplates": false`

and ignore the error for "Some language features are not available".

Comment: Beware, this should not be the accepted answer. Disabling "strictTemplates" also disables other features that are not related to this issue...

Comment: Bad advice.... If you want template errors at compile time instead of finding them in production, keep this on.

Comment: what's the alternative in angular 15?

Answer (score 27):

There are various suggestions here to cast your `AbstractControl` to `FormControl`.  You can also replace the reference in the template with e.g. `[formControl]="$any(ngControl.control)"`.  The [`$any()` cast operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-expression-operators#any-type-cast-function) is the only built in casting operator I could find for the templating engine today.

If this bothers you, please go upvote and subscribe to [this extremely popular, longstanding issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13721) that could actually provide a decent fix.

Answer (score 14):

It's a problem with the "cast". You can create a getter (it's very similar when we mannage a FormArray, that we create a getter casting a FormArray)

```
get control(){
   return this.ngControl.control as FormControl
}
```

And replace in your .html all the `ngControl.control` by `control`

Answer (score 4):

**Using template pipe cast with generics *TypeSafe*:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Cast super type into type using generics
 * Return Type obtained by assignment type.
 */

@Pipe({ name: 'cast' })
export class CastPipe implements PipeTransform {
     /**
     * Cast (S: SuperType) into (T: Type) using @Generics.
     * @param value S: SuperType obtained from input type.
     * @returns (T: Type) obtained by assignment type.
     */
    transform<S, T extends S>(value: S): T {
        return <T>value;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
[formControl]="ngControl.control | cast"
```

**Update 1:** [Optional pipe argument to pass Class Type explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69467612/1283715).

**Update 2: [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)**

> Instead, we need a way of capturing the type of the argument in such a
> way that we can also use it to denote what is being returned.

Comment: Extended my answer with [optional pipe argument to pass Class Type explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69467612/1283715)

Comment: I works, but I fail to understand how Typescript picks up type from an assignment. Can you provide any documentation links about this?

Comment: @undsoft check my update including doc reference.

Comment: I understand generics, I guess I wasn't aware that they can be used "in reverse" to infer return type from assignment.

Comment: @undsoft The doc show in examples that `we can also use it to denote what is being returned.`

Comment: This solution does not work for me. But this does work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67834802/template-error-type-abstractcontrol-is-not-assignable-to-type-formcontrol/72517767#72517767

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and I noticed that there was an issue of casting form['controls'] to FormControl which is because form['controls'] is of AbstractControls type. Here is my solution implemented in your Code.
**text-input.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, Input, Self } from '@angular/core';
    import { ControlValueAccessor, NgControl, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-text-input',
      templateUrl: './text-input.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./text-input.component.css']
    })
    // We need to implement a control value accessor
    export class TextInputComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input() label: string;
      @Input() type = 'text';
      @Input() abstractcontrol!: AbstractControl;

      ngControl!: NgControl;

      constructor() {}

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.control = this.abstractcontrol as NgControl;
      }
    }
```

**register.component.html**

```js
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="register()" autocomplete="off">
    <h2 class="text-center text-primary">Sign up</h2>
    <hr>
    <app-text-input [abstractcontrol]='registerForm.controls["username"]' [label]='"Username"'></app-text-input>

    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-dark mr-2" type="submit">Register</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success mr-2" (click)="cancel()" type="button">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am also new to Angular. Please feel free to point out any problems in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom reactive forms control, you may need to add providers for your component metadata.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-input',
  templateUrl: './text-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-input.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => TextInputComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks, @Kevin Zhang, but still facing the same error.

Comment: Could you please add your code to Stackbliz.com, so I can do some debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old thread but any one experiencing the same issue with Angular 13... kindly follow the following. Looks like the issue is resolved in Angular 14

**text-input.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, Self } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, FormControl, NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-input',
  templateUrl: './text-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-input.component.css']
})
export class TextInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  
  @Input() label: string = '';
  @Input() labelMustMatch: string = '';
  @Input() placeHolder: string = '';
  @Input() type: string = 'text';

  constructor(@Self() public ngControl: NgControl) { 
    this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    
  }
}
```

**text-input.component.html**

```
<input 
[class.is-invalid]="ngControl.invalid && ngControl.touched && ngControl.dirty"
type="{{ type }}"
class="form-control" 
[formControl]="$any(ngControl.control)"  
placeholder="{{ placeHolder }}"
>

<!--required-->
<div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="ngControl.control?.errors?.['required']">
    {{label}} is required
</div>
<!--minlength-->
<div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="ngControl.control?.errors?.['minlength']">
    {{label}} must be minimum {{ngControl.control?.errors?.['minlength']['requiredLength']}} characters
</div>
<!--maxlength-->
<div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="ngControl.control?.errors?.['maxlength']">
    {{label}} must be maximum {{ngControl.control?.errors?.['maxlength']['requiredLength']}} characters
</div>
<!--onlyChar-->
<div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="ngControl.control?.errors?.['onlyChar']">
    {{label}} must be only characters
</div>
<!--onlyCharWithSpace-->
<div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="ngControl.control?.errors?.['onlyCharWithSpace']">
    {{label}} must be only characters and space
</div>
<!--mustMatch-->
<div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="ngControl.control?.errors?.['mustMatch']">
    {{labelMustMatch}} do not match
</div>
<!--passwordStrength-->
<div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="ngControl.control?.errors?.['passwordStrength']">
    {{label}} must have an upper case, lower case and a number
</div>
```

**site-register.component.ts**
Add the getters for the three controls

```
  get registerFormUsernameControl(): FormControl {
    return this.registerForm.get('userName') as FormControl;
    //return this.rf['userName'] as FormControl;
  }
 
  get registerFormPasswordControl(): FormControl {
    return this.registerForm.get('password') as FormControl;
    //return this.rf['password'] as FormControl;
  }
 
  get registerFormConfirmPasswordControl(): FormControl {
    return this.registerForm.get('confirmPassword') as FormControl;
    //return this.rf['confirmPassword'] as FormControl;
  }
```

**site-register.component.html**

```
<app-text-input [formControl]="registerFormUsernameControl" [label]="'User name'" [placeHolder]="'user name'"></app-text-input>
<app-text-input [formControl]="registerFormPasswordControl" [type]="'password'" [label]="'Password'" [placeHolder]="'password'"></app-text-input>
<app-text-input [formControl]="registerFormConfirmPasswordControl" [type]="'password'" [label]="'Confirm password'" [placeHolder]="'confirm password'" [labelMustMatch]="'Password and confirm password'"></app-text-input>
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace the type of control parameter from `AbstractControl` to `Control`

Answer (score -3):

Are you using Angular 12 in strict mode here? If so change your `tsconfig.json` file and set:

```
"strictTemplates": false
```

It's works for me.

Comment: This answer duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/a/67037452/854664