# How to type an observable using an async pipe within Angular

Tags: html, angular, rxjs

I am trying to type an observable that utilizes the async pipe. Right now I am currently getting the error:

```
Property 'meatCount' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
```

```
<ng-template let-wowzers>
  <my-component
    class="my-component-class"
    [myProp]="(wowzers.testObservable$ | async)?.meatCount"
  >
  </my-component>
</ng-template>
```

The async pipe returns an object of type: Store

```
class Store {
   meatCount: number;
}
```

I know that there is a workaround where we would simply do something like:

```
<ng-template let-wowzers>
  <my-component
    class="my-component-class"
    [myProp]="getTypeStore(wowzers.testObservable$ | async)?.meatCount"
  >
  </my-component>
</ng-template>
```

Where the getTypeStore would return something like so:

```
  public getTypeStore = (store: Store): Store => store;
```

But is there another way to more effectively handle this problem? I am a little lost on how to type the observable using the async pipe within the html page within Angular?

Comment: How is `testObservable$` typed?

Comment: `[myProp]="getTypeStore(wowzers.testObservable$ | async)?.meatCount"` is not a good idea. See here: https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried giving a type to your observable in the component

```
wowzeers: {testObservable$: Observable<Store>} | undefined;
```

Comment: How can you do that for a template variable?

Comment: I would look at how to type it in the component somehow by going back to the original thing you are casting the variable from.  Angular will infer from that.  Otherwise, you would have to do something out of the box like type pipe https://stackoverflow.com/a/66154034/8698374