# VsCode Angular IntelliSense doesnt' work with cdkVirtualFor

Tags: angular, intellisense, tsconfig, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll, angular-language-service

I've installed the [VsCode Angular Language Service Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=loiane.angular-extension-pack) and I enabled strictTemplates in my `.tsconfig`.

It works almost like a charm. But I have a strange case. If you take a look at the images below, you will see that when the directive `ngFor` is used, everything works fine. IntelliSense detects the type of `let test`. But when using `cdkVirtualFor` it just gives me the type `any` back.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG9ws.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD6Yi.png)

I tried searching for solutions online, but I didn't really find anything.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/737)  it was fixed and you just need to use `strictTemplate` rule. It may be a stupid question, but is that what you mean with _I enabled strict mode_   ?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Thanks for the try, but I saw this post and it didn't help much. Thanks for the help tho :). Sorry about the confusion with the term "strict mode", I meant strictTemplates. (For future readers, I have edited my question)

Comment: you can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45964576/type-casting-within-a-template-in-angular-2/66154034#66154034

Comment: Thanks for the help @smnbbrv. This actually works great. But it still feels just like a hack and not like a good solution.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Note, this community discourages the use of images when text would do ([see here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)).  Please put the errors you want to share inline.

Comment: Thanks for the input @postylem, but I can't show what VsCode's IntelliSense suggests me when hovering over the variable if i would put the code inline. I could, but I think that images are more clear for any readers.

Comment: It seems `static ngTemplateContextGuard` was missing, which prevented Ivy's type-checker from infering the correct type. According to [this](https://github.com/angular/components/pull/27276#pullrequestreview-1474135747) it should be fixed in Angular's V17. Let's wait and see :)