# conditions for select - HTML or Javascript/Jquery

Tags: html, angular, if-statement, select

I have the following code:

```
<select  class="form-control" required>
   <option *ngFor="let car of cars" type="text">{{car.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

my problem is that i can get just a name, so `*ngFor` fails.
is there a way in **HTML** to make a condition like. If not **Javascript** or **Jquery**

```
     //There are more than 1 option
if(options.length>1){<option *ngFor="let car of cars" type="text">{{car.Name}}</option>}

//There is only an option
    else {<option *ngIf="car" type="text">{{car.Name}}</option>}
```

**Car**

```
export class Car {
  id: String;
  name: [{
        brand: String,
    }
  }]
}
```

`JSON` returns an `Array[]` when there are more than one element. If not, it returns an `Object{}` so I can not use `*ngFor`

**Solved**
The problem was in the back-end, and not in the front-end

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: Your original code seems fine. If there is only one car in the collection then you will only get one Name displayed.

Comment: It is a JSON and if it is just one Name it is not an Array, just an object. So i can not use ngFor

Comment: Then you don't need any angular directives, just `{{cars.Name}}`. If `cars` only represents a single car then name it `car`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*ngIf` directive like:

```
<select id="oneICO" class="form-control" required *ngIf="cars.length > 1">
   <option *ngFor="let car of cars">{{car.Name}}</option>
</select>

<input type="text" *ngIf="cars.length < 2">{{car.Name}}</input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking if a variable is an array in the template is sort of nasty [How to check type of variable in ngIf in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511055/how-to-check-type-of-variable-in-ngif-in-angular2)

It would be better to check if `!(cars instanceof Array)` and then turn it into an array in your javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

In html you can use ngif in angular2

```
 <div *ngIf="options.length>1">
    <option *ngFor="let car of cars" type="text">{{car.Name}}</option>
  </div>
```

or simple put the next code in html

```
<option *ngIf="options.length == 1 " type="text">{{car.Name}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

`cars` is not a collection so you don't need any angular directives:

```
<select id="oneICO" class="form-control" required>
   <option>{{cars.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

In which case, rename `cars` to `car` so that it signifies a single item.

[It is a little pointless, though, have a `select` with only a single `option`.]

---

Note that an `option` does not have a `type` attribute.

Comment: I have edited my question cause i think that it was not clear

Answer (score 0):

Your original code is fine. There's nothing wrong with it.

```
<select id="oneICO" class="form-control" required>
  <option *ngFor="let car of cars" type="text">{{car.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

If you have single car, make an array of single element and it will work just fine.

```
cars = ['Honda']
```

If you have multiple cars, you'll have something like this.

```
cars = ['Honda', 'Toyota', 'Mitsubishi']
```

Comment: No. The problem is that cars is not always an Array []. Sometimes it is just an object {}