# Read out Objects of an Observable in a Service in Angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable

card.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CardService {
drugs: Drugs = [];

public objObservable: any;
private objObserver: any;

constructor() {
    this.objObservable = new Observable((localObserver) => {
        this.objObserver = localObserver; // Convert this.objObserver from any to an observer object
        this.objObserver.next(this.drugs); // Connect this.drugs to observable object by observer
    });
}

getDrugs(): Observable<Drugs> {
    return this.objObservable;
}

addDrug(newDrug: Drug) {
    this.drugs = [...this.drugs, newDrug];
    return this.objObserver.next(this.drugs);
}

removeDrug(neo4jId: string) {
    this.drugs = this.drugs.filter((item: Drug) => item.neo4jId !== neo4jId);
    return this.objObserver.next(this.drugs);
}
```

I am using this service to add and remove some Drugs into an Observable in my Home component.
In the card Component i want to loop in this Observable and give out the values i need to show in the html.

card.component.html

```
<div>
{{  this.cardService.getDrugs() | async | json }}
</div>
```

this one is giving me all the output of the observable as json and then i tried to do something like

```
<div>
{{  (this.cardService.getDrugs() | async | json).type }}
</div>
```

to only show me the type, but this is not working.
How can i loop through all Objects in this observable and output only the types f.e.?

Drug Model:

```
export interface Drug {

neo4jId?: string;
drugId?: string;
tradingName: string;
type: string;
quantity: number;
expire: Date;
entryDate: Date;
lastModified?: Date;
slot: number;
substances?: Substance[]
};

export interface Drugs extends Array<Drug> { }
```

Comment: It is a little unclear. Is `drugs: Drugs = [];` an array of type `Drugs`. Or is it meant to be `drugs = Drug[]` an array of type `Drug`?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific purpose to separating `drugs` container and it's observable? Please check if the following fulfills the requirement

```js
@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CardService {
 private drugsSource = new BehaviorSubject<Array<Drug>>([]);
 private drugs$ = this.drugsSource.asObservable();

 constructor() { }

 getDrugs(): any {
   return this.drugs$;
 }

 addDrug(newDrug: Drug) {
   this.drugsSource.next([...this.drugsSource.getValue(), newDrug]);
 }

 removeDrug(neo4jId: string) {
   this.drugsSource.next(this.drugsSource.getValue().filter((item: Drug) => item.neo4jId !== neo4jId));
 }
}
```

It doesn't make much sense to return obserables from add and remove method when there is a separate get method. So subscribe to it whenever you add or remove values.

Component

```js
this._cardService.addDrug(drug);
this._cardService.getDrugs().subscribe(drugs => { 
  // handle value 
});

// similarly for removing
this._cardService.removeDrug('34');
this._cardService.getDrugs().subscribe(drugs => { 
  // handle value 
});
```

**Update**
To display type in HTML, you need to write a pipe.

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'drugsType'
})
export class TypeOfPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(drugs: any): any {
    let result = [];
    for (const drug of drugs) {
      let obj = {};
      for (const key of Object.keys(drug)) {
        obj[key] = typeof drug[key];
      }
      result.push(obj);
    }
    return result;
  }

}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scgqbw)

Comment: the service is working fine, i just would like to know how to output the content of the observable in my html

Comment: That is difficult to say without looking at the structure of the `Drugs` model. Could you please update the model in the question?

Comment: i added the drug model into the description, is that helping ?

Comment: Yes, can you create a mock up of what you would like to display in HTML?

Comment: There is no type operator in HTML. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511166/6513921). You need a write own pipe. I've update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a BehaviorSubject for what you are trying to accomplish.
See if this works for you. You can check a working example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-service-behaviorsubject

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

export interface Drug {
  neo4jId: string;
  Description: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CardService {
  private bsDrugs = new BehaviorSubject<Drug[]>([])

  constructor() {
  }

  getDrugs(): Observable<Drug[]> {
      return this.bsDrugs;
  }

  addDrug(newDrug: Drug) {
      let drugs = [...this.bsDrugs.value, newDrug];
      this.bsDrugs.next(drugs);
  }

  removeDrug(neo4jId?: string) {
    let drugs = [];
    if (neo4jId) {
      drugs = this.bsDrugs.value.filter((item: Drug) => item.neo4jId !== neo4jId);
    } else {
      if (this.bsDrugs.value.length > 0 ) {
        this.bsDrugs.value.pop();
        drugs = this.bsDrugs.value;
      }
    }

    this.bsDrugs.next(drugs);
  }
}
```

Comment: i am just asking how to output this in my html. Everything is working good in my service

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem like this

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-card',
templateUrl: './card.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./card.component.css']
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {
  drugList: Observable<Array<Drug>>;
  subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private cardService: CardService) { }

ngOnInit() {

 this.drugList = this.cardService.getDrugs();

}

}
```

and in the html

```
<div *ngFor="let drug of drugList | async">
  <p>{{   drug.tradingName    }}</p>
  <p>{{   drug.type  }}</p>
  <p>{{   drug.quantity  }}</p>
  <p>{{   drug.slot  }}</p>
</div>
```

the style can be made better of course. 
My point was just how to get access to the Objects in the Observable