# How do I sort a collection (dictionary) by a key in it we want in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, dictionary

I use javascript dictionary for a big list , and complete it like under code

```
var child = { 
     id:1,
     values:30
};

var array = [] ; 
array.push(child);
```

I want sorting this array by value field my problem is that I can't find a javascript method for it I can write it manually, but it is my last hope

Comment: Try `array.sort(function(a,b){return a.values-b.values})`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterate over a Javascript associative array in sorted order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890807/iterate-over-a-javascript-associative-array-in-sorted-order)

Comment: Please google your problem before asking about it on SO. Sorting dicts has been done numerous times before, and there is plenty of info about it available.

Comment: i google it and i dont find any answer for sorting list of dictionary by a dictionary keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a custom callback (aka [comparerfunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)) for the sorting. Something along the lines of <sup>**1**</sup>:

```
array.sort( function (a,b) { return +a.value - +b.value; } );
```

<sup>**1**</sup> I'm assuming `value` should be numeric and to be sure the sorting will be numeric the `value` property is explicitly converted to a number using `+`

Comment: Those `+` aren't necessary because `String - String` is `String - +String`, which then means `String - Number` and a String subtracting a number will cast the String to a Number.