# How to implement a map or sorted-set in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

Javascript has arrays which use numeric indexes `["john", "Bob", "Joe"]` and objects which can be used like associative arrays or "maps" that allow string keys for the object values `{"john" : 28, "bob": 34, "joe" : 4}`.

In PHP it is easy to both **A) sort by values** (while maintaining the key) and **B) test for the existence of a value** in an associative array.

```
$array = ["john" => 28, "bob" => 34, "joe" => 4];

asort($array); // ["joe" => 4, "john" => 28, "bob" => 34];

if(isset($array["will"])) { }
```

How would you acheive this functionality in Javascript?

This is a common need for things like weighted lists or sorted sets where you need to keep a single copy of a value in data structure (like a tag name) and also keep a weighted value.

This is the best I've come up with so far:

```
function getSortedKeys(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    keys = keys.sort(function(a,b){return obj[a]-obj[b]});

    var map = {};
    for (var i = keys.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      map[keys[i]] = obj[keys[i]];
    };

    return map;
}

var list = {"john" : 28, "bob": 34, "joe" : 4};
list = getSortedKeys(list);
if(list["will"]) { }
```

Comment: For the first line you might want to use: Object.keys https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: As soon as you have keys and values, you'll have objects. Objects are not sorted. But this is very inspiring: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key)

Comment: @Wikunia, thank you. I updated the code. http://stackoverflow.com/a/890877/99923

Comment: Do you want to sort by key or value? Cause your js script orders by key but your php one by value. And as the answer mentioned out an object is unordered.

Comment: @bhantol, that is no improvement on the answer I already provided and in fact adds a dependency on jQuery just for a simple operation.

Comment: @Wikunia, both sort by value while maintaining the `key -> value` relationship.

Comment: @Xeoncross a sorry my fault!

Comment: @Xeoncross - wrong link - here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/5467142/2103767

Comment: Note: [Associative Arrays or "Maps"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) *do not imply ordering*: "Usually, for such an [iteration] operation, the order in which the bindings are returned may be arbitrary." That is a PHP-ism / implementation detail.

Comment: ...but sorted sets do, hence the question.

Comment: It's not [just] a Map then. It's a Sorted Set (or whatever the particular implementation desired is).

Comment: Your solution is wrongYou can't return a sorted object in javascript because the standard ES5 doesn't guarantee order when iterating over object properties.  Just keep both sorted array and map, use array for iterating and map for checking if exists.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [this answer by Luke Schafer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/890877/99923) I think I might have found a better way to handle this by extending the Object.prototype:

```
// Sort by value while keeping index
Object.prototype.iterateSorted = function(worker, limit)
{
    var keys = Object.keys(this), self = this;
    keys.sort(function(a,b){return self[b] - self[a]});

    if(limit) {
        limit = Math.min(keys.length, limit);
    }

    limit = limit || keys.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        worker(keys[i], this[keys[i]]);
    }
};

var myObj = { e:5, c:3, a:1, b:2, d:4, z:1};

myObj.iterateSorted(function(key, value) {
    console.log("key", key, "value", value)
}, 3);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xeoncross/kq3gbwgh/

Comment: Your code doesn't work because of this line: `keys = keys.sort(function(a,b){return this[a] - this[b]});`. In context of sort function `this` is `keys`, not `myObj`

Comment: Thank you, I was just wondering what I was missing. I can't believe I forgot scope.

Comment: You should do like this: `var self = this; keys = keys.sort(function(a,b){return self [a] - self [b]});`. See my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why none of these answers mentions the existence of a built-in JS class, [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Seems to be an ES6 addition, perhaps that's why.

Ideally override either `add` **or** `keys` below... NB overriding `keys` doesn't even need access to the `Set` object's prototype. Of course you could override these methods for the entire `Set` class. Or make a subclass, `SortedSet`.

```
  const mySet = new Set();

  const mySetProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(mySet);
  const addOverride = function(newObj){
    const arr = Array.from(this);
    arr.add(newObj);
    arr.sort(); // or arr.sort(function(a, b)...)
    this.clear();
    for(let item of arr){
      mySetProto.add.call(this, item);
    }
  }
  mySet.add = addOverride;
    
  const keysOverride = function(){
    const arr = Array.from(this);
    arr.sort(); // or arr.sort(function(a, b)...)
    return arr[Symbol.iterator]();
  }
  mySet.keys = keysOverride;
```

Usage:

```
mySet.add(3); mySet.add(2); mySet.add(1); mySet.add(2);
for(let item of mySet.keys()){console.log(item)};
```

Prints out:

> 1 ... 2 ... 3

NB `Set.keys()` returns not the items in the `Set`, but an **iterator**. You could choose to return the sorted array instead, but you'd obviously be breaking the class's "contract".

Which one to override? Depends on your usage and the size of your `Set`. If you override both you will be duplicating the sort activity, but in most cases it probably won't matter.

NB The `add` function I suggest is of course naive, a "first draft": rebuilding the entire set each time you `add` could be pretty costly. There are clearly much cleverer ways of doing this based on examining the existing elements in the `Set` and using a compare function, a binary tree structure*, or some other method to determine **where** in it to add the candidate for adding (I say "candidate" because it would be rejected if an "identical" element, namely itself, were already found to be present).

The question also asks about similar arrangements for a sorted map... in fact it turns out that ES6 has a new [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) class which lends itself to similar treatment ... and also that `Set` is just a specialised `Map`, as you might expect.

* e.g. https://github.com/Crizstian/data-structure-and-algorithms-with-ES6/tree/master/10-chapter-Binary-Tree

Answer (score 1):

With ES6 you could choose to extend the `Map` constructor/class with a `sort` method that takes an optional compare function (just like arrays have). That `sort` method would take two arguments, each of which are key/value pairs so that the sorting can happen on either the keys or the values (or both).

The `sort` method will rely on the documented behaviour of Maps that entries are iterated in insertion order. So this new method will visit the entries according to the sorted order, and then delete and immediately re-insert them.

Here is how that could look:

```js
class SortableMap extends Map {
    sort(cmp = (a, b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0])) {
        for (const [key, value] of [...this.entries()].sort(cmp)) {
            this.delete(key);
            this.set(key, value); // New keys are added at the end of the order
        }
    }
}
// Demo
const mp = new SortableMap([[3, "three"],[1, "one"],[2, "two"]]);
console.log("Before: ", JSON.stringify([...mp])); // Before
mp.sort( (a, b) => a[0] - b[0] ); // Custom compare function: sort numerical keys
console.log(" After: ", JSON.stringify([...mp])); // After
```

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't sort an object. But if you do: [Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value)

If you want to sort an array, let's say the following

```
var arraylist = [{"john" : 28},{ "bob": 34},{ "joe" : 4}];
```

You can always use `Array.prototype.sort` function.
Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: So how do you test for the existence of a value then? A for loop?

Comment: `arrayList.sort(function comparer(a, b){ /* check against a and b values here */})`  If you know that the arraylist items are always compsed by key value, then check what properties are owned by `a` and `b` and check its values (for instance `a[ownedPropName]`)

Comment: Running another sort over the values *just to check for the existence* of a value is a bad idea. Perhaps you didn't see the second part of the question...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code look like what you want:

```
Object.prototype.asort = function(){
    var retVal = {};
    var self = this;
    var keys = Object.keys(this);
    keys = keys.sort(function(a,b){return self[a] - self[b]});
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        retVal[keys[i]] = this[keys[i]];
    }
    return retVal;
}
var map = {"john" : 28, "bob": 34, "joe" : 4}
var sortedMap = map.asort();//sortedMap["will"]: undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the open source project [jinqJs](http://www.jinqJs.com) its easy.

See [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/tford/qwka154r/)

```
var result = jinqJs()
                .from([{"john" : 28},{ "bob": 34},{ "joe" : 4}])
                .orderBy([{field: 0}])
                .select();
```

Comment: Thank you for [sharing this library](https://github.com/fordth/jinqJs/blob/master/jinqjs.js#L388), but this is relatively simple task in most languages and I would like to know how best write this rather than using some library.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of OrderedMap.
Use the functions `get()` and `set()` to extract or push key value pairs to the `OrderedMap`.
It is internally using an array to maintain the order.

```js
class OrderedMap {
  constructor() {
    this.arr = [];
    return this;
  }
  get(key) {
    for(let i=0;i<this.arr.length;i++) {
      if(this.arr[i].key === key) {
        return this.arr[i].value;
      }
    }
    return undefined;
  }

  set(key, value) {
    for(let i=0;i<this.arr.length;i++) {
      if(this.arr[i].key === key) {
        this.arr[i].value = value;
        return;
      }
    }
    this.arr.push({key, value})
  }

  values() {
    return this.arr;
  }
}

let m = new OrderedMap();
m.set('b', 60)
m.set('a', 10)
m.set('c', 20)
m.set('d', 89)

console.log(m.get('a'));

console.log(m.values());
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/js-sdsl/js-sdsl

The `OrderedMap` in Js-sdsl maybe helpful.

This is a sorted-map which implement refer to C++ STL Map.

```js
/*
 * key value
 * 1   1
 * 2   2
 * 3   3
 * Sorted by key.
 */
const mp = new OrderedMap(
    [1, 2, 3].map((element, index) => [index, element])
);
mp.setElement(1, 2);        // O(logn)
mp.eraseElementByKey(1)     // O(logn)

// custom comparison function
mp = new OrderedMap(
    [1, 2, 3].map((element, index) => [index, element]),
    (x, y) => x - y
);

// enable tree iterator index (enableIndex = true)
console.log(new OrderedMap([[0, 1], [1, 1]], undefined, true).begin(),next().index);   // 1
```