# How to avoid and make sure about my random number un repeated..?

Tags: jquery

In my application, i am using datepicker from jqueryui, It needs the unique id's for each input element. to do that,

i use this function (example):

```
   var x = 100;

    $("a").on("click", function(){
        console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * x ));
    })
```

my question is, how to i assure, that no random number will not get repeated. so, i can avoid the duplicate id's.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: How about increment instead of random?

Comment: make a global variable and increment it every time you're creating new `input` element

Comment: I think instead of this you can use  each loop to traverse all inputs and use index to attach with there Ids to set unique Ids.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625551/jquery-math-random-number-without-repeating-a-previous-number?rq=1

Comment: @3gwebtrain Why dont you use a class instead of IDs to bind datepicker?

Comment: using class will be better in this. You can use `hasClass` to check then. But the main issue is that you are trying to assing ID's on each click??? what if the user clicks on the same element again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = 100,
    usedNumbers = [];

$("a").on("click", function(){
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * x );

    if ($.inArray(number, usedNumbers)) {
        number = Math.floor(Math.random() * x );
    }
    else {
        usedNumbers.push(number);
    }

    console.log(number);
    console.log(usedNumbers);
});
```

It could happen that you do get an already taken number with this, so if necessary, you should create a loop which only finishes as soon as a new, untaken number was created

Comment: Using random numbers for variable/control ids is a bad idea. And then having to check whether the value has been used again each time you add a new one? Isn't that unnecessarily taxing on the performance???

Comment: Wow, random control IDs getting chosen as an answer... This website is going down the drain...

Answer (score 1):

Using random to set custom ID is not a good idea.
Why not just make an array and increment ID for each element ?

Comment: Is it answer or comment  ? I think this should be in comment section because its not an answer of  problem described.

Comment: You're right, but shouldn't I give a way for a better solution instead of give the answer to a bad question ?

Comment: I agree with FC, using random numbers for variable/control ids is a bad idea. And then having to check whether the value has been used again each time you add a new one? Ridiculous...

Comment: Even if you're cloning, answer is the same. Just increment the ID counter and give the result to your clone !

Answer (score 1):

Don't use random numbers, use a counter instead.

```
var x = 100;

$("a").on("click", function(){
  x++;
  console.log("id" + x);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Object capable of generating random ids through recursion triggered by filtering result

    var uniqueRandom = {
        randoms: [],
        getRandom: function(){
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); //Make this your size, I used 10 for easy testing
            if(this.randoms.filter(function(elem){ return elem == random}).length > 0){
               return this.getRandom();
            }else{
               this.randoms.push(random);
               return random;
            }
        }
    }

//Usage
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       console.log(uniqueRandom.getRandom());
    }
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/q6SRs/1/