# Get array property value using variable

Tags: javascript

```
var type = "chance"; //or "chest" ;
var title = cards.type[0].title; //type is variable not an actual property of cards
```

Instead of typing the name of a property I want to use a variable, because it can be either `cards.chance[0].title` or `cards.chest[0].title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `[]` syntax:

```
var type = "chance"; //or "chest" ;
var title = cards[type][0].title;
```