# Making p5js random more random

Tags: p5.js

When I do this, it's not exactly very random. I'll get very repetitive sequences of numbers. Is there any alternative to make this more random?

```
const pastelColors = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
  new p5(p => {
    p.randomSeed(index+1);
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(p.random(pastelColors.length));
    console.log(pastelColors[randomIndex]);
  })
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating non-repeating random numbers in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806210/generating-non-repeating-random-numbers-in-js)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to "shuffle" the array:

```js
const pastelColors = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const shuffledColors = pastelColors.sort((a, b) => 0.5 - Math.random());

for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    new p5(p => {
        const randomColor = shuffledColors[index] 
        console.log(randomColor);
    })
}
```