# don't repeat any items from math.random

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this to get a random item from my array (and append it to each list item)

```
   $('li').each(function(){
       var items = Array('the','and','to','a');
       var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
       $(this).append(item);
    });
```

I'm sure this is a quick thing but I don't really know where to look. How can I make sure there are no repeating items?

Comment: Maybe remove the item after getting it? This means that you need to declare `items` before the `each` loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery math random number without repeating a previous number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625551/jquery-math-random-number-without-repeating-a-previous-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Working Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7WVpD/1/)

you need to remove the used value from the array.

```
  var items = Array('the', 'and', 'to', 'a');
  $('li').each(function () {
      var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)
      var item = items[randomNum];
      $(this).append(item);
      items.splice(randomNum, 1);
      
  });
```

Se [your Demo on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7WVpD/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var items = new Array('the','and','to','a');
$('li').each(function(){
    var item = items.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length), 1);
    $(this).append(item);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qsbFz/)

Answer (score 0):

So you want the elements randomized but not repeating? Then what you're looking for is a *random permutation*. If you want a quick'n'dirty solution, just randomly swap elements in your array. If you want a uniformly distributed random permutation, have a look at Eric Lippert's articles on the subject: http://ericlippert.com/2013/05/02/producing-permutations-part-six/