# How to check if 'string1' is in 'string1, string2, string3, .. stringn'

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I am appending the `.text()` of an anchor to an input when its dragged and dropped to it.

The thing is that I need them comma sepated and not repeated:

If I am tying to add `'string 1'` to the input when the value is already `'bla, ble, string1'`, I need to prevent to be duplicated,

How would you do it?

My first guess is to make an explode by `','` and combine it with a for loop, but I don't think that is really optimized at all.

Comment: Why not use a regex to match `string1` between two commas?  Of course you'd need to account for it being first or last element too when building your regex.

Comment: BTW, is there a good reason why you need to store a big string? Why don't you keep the easier to manipulate "exploded" array instead?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890782/javascript-function-inarray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Basic Idea**

```
function addParameter(str, param) {
    var re = new RegExp("[^,]\\s?" + param + "[,$]","g");
    if( !re.test(str) ) {
        str += ( (str.length>0) ? ", " : "") + param;
    }
    return str;
}

var orgStr = "abc, def, hij";

//This exists so it will not be added
var newStr = addParameter( orgStr, "def" );
console.log( newStr );

//This does not exist so it will be added to the end
newStr = addParameter( orgStr, "xyz" );
console.log( newStr );
```

**Explain Regular Expression**

- `[^,]\\s?` - Says match beginning of string or a comma followed by an optional space character
- `param` - matches your string passed in
- `[,$]` - Says match a comma or the end of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your existing CSV string to an array, append your value, and then convert it back to a string:

```
//Create an array from the CSV list
var myVals = $("#YourElement").val().split(",");
var isDupe = false;

for(var i = 0; i < myVals.length; i++) {
    if(myVals[i].indexOf("YourNewValue") != -1) {
        isDupe = true;
        break;
    }
}

//use .push() to append your value to the end of the array
if(!isDupe) {
    myVals.push("YourNewValue");

    //Invoking .toString() on an array creates a CSV list
    $("#YourElement").val(myVals.toString());
}
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/sc9fq/).

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet, Please see updated answer for dupe checking.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your fiddle you can;

```
var myVals = $("#YourElement").val().split(",");
var wantToAdd = "cakey";

if ($.inArray(wantToAdd, myVals) === -1)
   myVals.push(wantToAdd);

$("#YourElement").val(myVals.join(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for reg exp or array-

```
var t=input.value, s= //text string;
if(t.indexOf(s)==-1)t.value=t+ ', '+s;
```