# How do I match ANY element of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I check if a variable is equal to any element of an array?

```
var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
var myVar; //myVar value is set to "One", "Two" or "Three" sometime later

myArray = ["One","Two","Three"];

myButton.onclick = function () {
    if (myVar === myArray) {
        alert ("it's a match!");
    } else {
                alert ("it's not a match!");
        }
};
```

Comment: The simplest and most efficient is to loop. If you want something fancy look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890782/javascript-function-inarray

Comment: You have to loop, but you can `break;` on the first match so you don' tneed to continue looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
myButton.onclick = function () {
    var i = myArray.length;
    while( i-- ) {
        if( myVar === myArray[i] ) {
            alert("it's a match");
            return;
        }
    }
    alert("it's not a match");
}
```

Comment: thanks for this! it's going to exit the while loop when i=0?

Comment: You reinventing indexOf() ?

Comment: Not really. If every browser supported it I would change my answer.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this solution. I don't quite have it yet. I mocked it up here: [http://jsfiddle.net/Y7wAY

Comment: Sorry, I had an error in my function but it is corrected now. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7wAY/1/)

Comment: I did finally get this working! Thanks so much for you help! :) I may have figured it out earlier but I had an issue where my global variable wasn't being recognized within the function. Once I moved the variable into the function, it started working. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1860777 Glad you got there :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop through `myArray` and check each element.

However, you can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) if you don't care about IE 8 or earlier.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm new to javascript, but when I hear people say that I normally see them do something like:
`var myArrayLength = myArray.length;`

but from what I can tell that only makes myArrayLength = 3. I guess I don't know what to do with that.

Comment: @user1860777 I don't understand how this relates to the question or this answer.

Comment: As I said, I'm new to javascript so I appreciate the info you provided. For now, I did it the oldschool way described by Bruno, but I'm happy to now know about indexOf. I'm sure I'll be using it soon.