# How to do IN in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript function inArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890782/javascript-function-inarray)

In Python, I can do multi-equivalence testing by doing:

```
if x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    do something
```

How would I do this in javascript?. Currently I'm doing:

```
if (x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 4 || x == 5) {
    do something
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JavaScript there is [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method:

```
if ([1,2,3,4,5].indexOf(x) > -1) {
    // do something
}
```

Note, that this method is not supported by some old browsers, so it is recommended to use [shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility).

By the way, [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator exists in JavaScript, and is primarily used for checking property existence in objects, for example:

```
"id" in { id: 123 } === true;
"id" in { ib: 123 } === false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch if you only want to specify the `x` variable once:

```
switch (x) {
  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3:
  case 4:
  case 5:
    // do something
}
```

If the values are really like in the example, you can just check the end values:

```
if (x >= 1 && x <= 5) {
  // do something
}
```