# How to realize function inArray (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to realize JavaScript (without using any libraries) function inArray, call examples of which are given below?

`inArray(15, [1, 10, 145, 8]) === false;
[23, 674, 4, 12].inArray(4) === true;`

Thank you very much!

Comment: [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: This has been answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890782/javascript-function-inarray/890808#890808

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
[23, 674, 4, 12].indexOf(4) >= 0 // evaluates to true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function inArray(val, arr){
        return arr.indexOf(val) > -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can attach functions to the prototype of `Array`.** [That this may cause problems has been thoroughly discussed elsewhere.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877005/extending-object-prototype-javascript)

```js
function inArray(needle, haystack) {
  return haystack.indexOf(needle) >= 0;
}
Array.prototype.inArray = function(needle) {
  return inArray(needle, this);
}

console.log(inArray(15, [1, 10, 145, 8])); // false
console.log([23, 674, 4, 12].inArray(4));  // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf with ES6 :

```
var inArray = (num, arr) => (arr.indexOf(num) === -1) ? false : true;
var myArray = [1 ,123, 45];
console.log(inArray(15, myArray)); // false
console.log(inArray(123, myArray));// true
```

Comment: [`indexOf` was already available with ES5.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.14)

Comment: Yes but arrow functions are not  :)

Comment: Neiter are they required to use `indexOf`